# Twitter API how to get protected tweets?

Tags: api, twitter

I searched a lot but still can't understand is it possible to get user's protected tweets after user/application authentication/authorization or not? If it's possible then maybe someone can point me in Twitter API doc where it's described, please?

Answer (score 4):

Protected tweets are any tweets in a protected user's timeline.

The doc you are looking for is here:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline

Here is the relevant part:
"User timelines belonging to protected users may only be requested when the authenticated user either “owns” the timeline or is an approved follower of the owner."

Comment: does a twitter application have the 'approved follower' status of the twitter user that created the twitter app? e.g. I'm an approved follower of a protected feed and I'm trying to create an application to read those protected tweets; is this possible? if so, how?

Comment: According to the sited Twitter doc, I think the answer is yes. If authenticated user in your application is an approved follower of a protected user, your application can use `statuses/user_timeline` to get their tweets.

Comment: Just verified that this is true; an application of an approved user CAN use `statuses/user_timeline` to access the protected tweets; however, you cannot stream them, which is what I originally wanted to do; but you can get around that by just putting the `statuses/user_timeline` into some kind of loop